# MAX and MIN to ignore ERROR or N/A

Tags: google-sheets

I already have a list of auto-generated numbers every few minutes, in which that number fluctuates, but sometimes the number is an ERROR or N/A.

For example my list is:

```
2
6
2
1
#N/A
#N/A
4
5
```

I want to get the max of this list so I would use `=max(B1:B)` which I’m taking the whole column. But in this situation the max will come out as #N/A. I need it to ignore the #N/A and ho straight to the highest number, in this case, 6.

As of now I’ve been manually deleting the error values, but I wanted to know if there was a better way to go about this.

That being said, is there also a way to delete all the #N/A values in a single sheet with a command or such?

Note, I need to take the whole column, so I can’t just do `=max(B1:B4,B7:B)` skipping the error values, as it’s an auto-generating list and the error values are random, not sure where they will land.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing up spreadsheet data when a column contains “#N/A”](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35523/summing-up-spreadsheet-data-when-a-column-contains-n-a)

Comment: i couldn’t get that to work, tried playing around with MAXIFS but nothing, still showing the max as #N/A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these formulas:

**Max**: `=MAXIFS(B3:B10,B3:B10,"<>#N/A")`

**Min**: `=MINIFS(B3:B10,B3:B10,"<>#N/A")`

---

**Sample**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thanks this worked, i forgot to put quotes over the #N/A. Thanks

Comment: also why did we need to list the b3:b10 twice?

Comment: You need to read and understand  the syntax for `MAXIFS`, it is VERY different to plain `MAX`. [MAXIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817?hl=en) syntax:  `MAXIFS(range, criteria_range1, criterion1)`. So the first "B3:B10" is the **Range** to be evaluated, the second "B3:B10" is the **Criteria Range**, and `"<>#N/A"` is the **criterion**. You can in fact have several criterion ranges/criteria but that is irrelevant to this question

Comment: got it that makes sense, thanks.